# Access Denied when I run 'rustup doc'

Tags: rust, rustup

When I run `rustup doc --book` I get this:

```
Access to the file was denied.

The file at file:///home/ken/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/share/doc/rust/html/index.html is not readable. It may have been removed, moved or file permissions may be preventing access.
```

I've reinstalled, I've tried using `chmod -R 777` on the directory. What else is there to try? The files are there.

Comment: Check with `getfacl` on the file and all parent folders. Check if `xdg-open file:///home/ken/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/share/doc/rust/html/index.html` works.

Comment: xdg_open results in the same access denied in browser. getfacl output indicates that the folders are owned by my user, and my username is under "group" as well as owner.

Comment: Can you try `xdg-open` with some other HTML file on your system? And can you try `xdg-mime query default text/html`?

Comment: default is firefox, xdg-open works fine with other HTML files

Comment: I'm a bit lost there. Last idea, can you try `xdg-mime query filetype index.html` and `xdg-mime query default $(xdg-mime query filetype index.html)`?

Comment: first returns: `text/html`, the second: `firefox_firefox.desktop`. again these are not on files in the Rust book dir. I had installed Rust via apt and then uninstalled, then reinstalled with the .sh script on the website. Baffling problem

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned by C F M G, if you use a browser installed with Snap then it will not work. I tried this with the Firefox snap and got the same message as you, but was able to access the docs when using Ungoogled Chromium installed from Flatpak.

Comment: Works on Edge 107.0.1418.35 installed from official microsoft web site.

Answer (score 3):

Check if you are using a browser on snap; in this case apparmor restricts access to local files.  you can fix this by replacing the snap version.

Answer (score 1):

What browser do you use?. I use Brave and the same error occured to me. I solved it changing the default browser to Chromium. After that, all work perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your browser.
It didn't work for me with Chromium but Firefox works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't open the Rust Document,the reason is chrom/firefix installed by snap!!!